# How would emigrants travel the railway lines going from Grajewo to Bremerhaven in 1911 and from Grajewo to Rotterdam in 1917?

Tags: travel, emigration

Grajewo was near the Prussian border.  It also had a railway station but I don't know its route.

As I understand it: There were several lines that can be used traveling from Bialystok to Bremerhaven switching trains, having to stop at control stations.

Travel could also be done starting at Łomża or Ostrołęka – I don't know which one would be better.  I heard going to Könisgberg first was a possibility.

How long would these routes take?

Comment: An interesting question would be, if (or how) immigration was possible in 1917 through the (neutral) Netherlands. Due to the blockade. leaving from Bremen would not have been possible. Entering the Netherlands probably would have been difficult.

Comment: Thank you.Yes, it is a more interesting question and better considering, that through my research I realize that getting to Bremen in 1917 would be impossible, which is why my grandmother went to Rotterdam.  So what possible way would she most likely go from Augustow, Poland to the Port of Rotterdam in 1917, which is what she did

Answer (score 5):

There are indeed several options to consider.

The first would be that [Grajewo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grajewo) was in Poland (Russian Empire), and thus in 1917 largely destroyed and [in German hands since September 1914 and until 1919](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalendarium_historii_Grajewa).

It is directly adjacent the border and the nearest Prussian town with a railway station would be [Prostken/Prostki.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prostki)

Since [1873 Grajewo had a train station](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grajewo) and thus a direct railway link, at first connecting Brest and Königsberg/Królewiec).
Königsberg seems to have meant a significant detour for the given destination — without much to gain in terms of speed, time or preferential connections. Similar results for Białystok, Łomża or Ostrołęka: all significant detours.

The border train station in Prostken-Saltzwedell was built in 1871 and connected also since 1873 Prostken to Grajewo in normal and Russian broad gauge rails.

Thus, starting in Grajewo itself means one border crossing. Starting in Prostken or after riding through Prostken then means no further control stations.

From there, the options multiply quickly:

[image]
(status of connections [1912](http://www.zeno.org/Roell-1912/I/Ro08128a), clickonpic)

Suggesting a route starting in Grajewo over Prostken to Lyck/Ełk, over Soldau or better Allenstein. Today, the same lines are called: Głomno–Białystok [Linia kolejowa nr 38](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linia_kolejowa_nr_38) and Czerwonka/(Rothfließ)–Ełk [Linia kolejowa nr 223](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linia_kolejowa_nr_223) (only partially usable in 1911, not fully until 1915) or [Linia kolejowa nr 219 (Olsztyn Główny–Ełk).](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linia_kolejowa_nr_219)

The route from Lyck/Ełk to Allenstein/Olsztyn had 6 connections per day in 1914:
[image]

Then perhaps Thorn, Posen or Schneidemühl, Frankfurt/Oder, Berlin to Stendal.

Most famously, emigrants then usually took the so called [America-line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America_Line) which connected Berlin and Stendal with Bremen and Bremerhaven:

[image]

The time for such a journey depends on the actual route taken. Which was then as is now also a matter of pricing. Faster trains would cost more. For the year 1917 it is of course much more difficult to firmly reconstruct any route or time that took, as war time priorities on the railways was not civilian passengers…

The actual timetables are largely online. Like [Hendschels Telegraph 1914](https://www.deutsches-kursbuch.de/1914/1_hoch.htm). If we piece together the connecting trains for the larger stations and prefer faster and longer reaching trains.

We see for example [fast direct connections like:](https://www.deutsches-kursbuch.de/1914/894_hoch.htm)

- Allenstein–Berlin: 9 hours
- Berlin-Bremerhaven: 7.5 hrs

Meaning one should have tried to get from Grajewo to Allenstein, then switch trains *once* more in Berlin.

[image]

If another destination, like Rotterdam, is the go-to port, then [TimeTableWorld](https://timetableworld.com/ttw-viewer?token=0e9e0cc9-e2bb-4ace-b0bb-7d1036047376) is currently *the* place to look it up. Crossing the [German-Netherlands border in 1917](https://encyclopedia.1914-1918-online.net/article/borders_the_netherlands) should have been possible in general, however strictly the Dutch tried to control the movements. At least [in mid-1915 that was evidently a possibility.](https://www.gjenvick.com/Passengers/Holland-America/NieuwAmsterdam-PassengerList-1915-05-29.html)

Interestingly, people stating their place of (former) residence as Grajewo and emigrating with Bremen-registered ships are quite few in numbers as currently still listed. [From the surviving records, none left from Bremen in 1911,](https://www.public-juling.de/passagierlisten/passagen.php?heimatort=Grajewo&lang=en) and rather obviously emigration from German ports came to halt in late 1914.

Just for comparison, a modern connection from Grajewo to Rotterdam looks quite similar, and appears to be not any faster whatsoever:

| station | time |
| --- | --- |
| Grajewo | departure 05:58 |
| Olsztyn Glowny | arrival 08:47 |
| Olsztyn Glowny | departure 09:52 |
| Zbaszynek | arrival 14:55 |
| Zbaszynek | departure: 16:14 to Berlin Hbf |
| Berlin Hbf | arrival: 18:16 |
| Berlin Hbf | departure: 21:21 |
| Duisburg Hbf | arrival: 01:55 |
| Duisburg Hbf | departure: 02:35 |
| Viersen | arrival: 03:12 |
| Viersen | departure: 05:33 |
| Venlo | arrival: 05:56n |
| Venlo | departure: 06:33 |
| Eindhoven Centraal | arival: 07:11 |
| Eindhoven Centraal | departure: 07:14 |
| Rotterdam Centraal | arrival: 08:16 |

Comment: Those are time-efficient choices. Would a series of local trains have been cheaper?

Comment: Most likely. Base tariff is per-km, but [Schnellzug](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnellzug) got a  [Zuschlag](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zuschlag_(Eisenbahn))…

Comment: Szczecin can't be right. Bydgoszcz or Poznań is more likly. There used to be trains going the route Allenstein (Olsztyn), through Danzig (Gdańsk) on to Stettin (Szczecin) and Berlin.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Indeed, the above is just a modern output from DB. Szczecin is the *train's* destination, not the passengers' who have to get off at Olsztyn (like you guessed correctly). I'll remove the train line destination to avoid such confusions.

Comment: [D 1/2 (Berlin–Eydtkuhnen) – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_1/2_(Berlin%E2%80%93Eydtkuhnen)): 1938/39 Berlin to Elbing (Elbląg) 6 hours, 31 minutes.(Express train)

Comment: Thank you everyone -- very helpful - especially the ones with the route shaded - I' keep trying to do that but haven't' been successful